# How can I solve the problem that method is not iterable?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

I have this Variational autoencoder and I want to use Adam for its optimizer but it has this error I don't know what is wrong here

```
class VAE(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        #encoder
        self.enc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(1200, 786),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Flatten()
        )
        self.mean = nn.Linear(1200, 2)
        self.log = nn.Linear(1200, 2)
        #decoder
        self.dec = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(2, 1200),
            nn.ReLU(),
        )

    def param(self, mu, Log):
        eps = torch.randn(2, 1200)
        z = mu + (eps * torch.exp(Log * 0.5))
        return z

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.enc(x)
        mu , log = self.mean(x), self.log(x)
        z = self.param(mu, log)
        x = self.dec(z)
        return x, mu, log

model = VAE()
optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.param, lr=0.01)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

and here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\khashayar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\VAE.py", line 40, in <module>
   optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.param, lr=0.01)
 File "C:\Users\khashayar\anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\torch\optim\adam.py", line 48, in __init__
   super(Adam, self).__init__(params, defaults)
 File "C:\Users\khashayar\anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\torch\optim\optimizer.py", line 47, in __init__
   param_groups = list(params)
TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable
```

how I can solve this?

Comment: Can you add the error stacktrace; which lines does it fail on

Comment: @saedx1 I update the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is probably in `model.param`.
param is a method, and as write in the error : "'method' object is not iterable". The optimizer should receive the model parameters, and not the method "param" of the model class.

Try convert `optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.param, lr=0.01)`  To `optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)`

Comment: The problem is probably in model.param. param is a method, and as write in the error : "'method' object is not iterable". The optimizer should receive the model parameters, and not the method "param" of the model class.